# NodeJS How to replace client side template with a Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following snippet in NodeJS. The code is from a tutorial I am working on, however would like for you to focus on the code within the `else if(req.url === "/"){...}` since that is where my problem is occurring. In this code I am using a `readStream` to get the contents of my HTML file, and I am using `pipe` to send these contents to the client's socket address.

So, what I am struggling with here is in wanting to use a stream to replace the `{title}` within my HTML file, with the `title` variable in my NodeJS file.

I know that you can do this *synchronously* via `readFileSync` but I want to try and use a stream, which I understand works *asynchronously* and is a best practice in NodeJS.

Thus due to my lack of understanding, I am not sure of the correct approach of how to use a stream to do this, any help is appreciated!

## NodeJS

```
'use strict'
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    html = "",
    title = "Hello World", // <-- template text
    obj = {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    };

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.url === '/api'){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
    else if(req.url === "/"){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        html = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html');

        html.on('data', function(data){ // <-- here I try to use the template text
            data = data.toString().replace('{title}', title);
            console.log(data);
        });

        html.pipe(res);
    }
    else {
        // Accessing a URL not handled or specified above
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning NodeJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: Right now this code does not replace the `{title}` in the HTML into `Hello World`. I have re-started my NodeJS server to make sure this is not some simple case of my code not being refreshed properly.

Disclaimer: I am learning NodeJS, please be kind :)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @jmugz3 good question, it is a logic error. I am not seeing the client HTML file being updated from `{title}` into `Hello World`. I will add this now on my question.

Comment: I don't think you are changing the data being sent but just a local variable in 'data' event handler function. do res.send(data) in this handler function instead of pipe outside.

Comment: @gp. Hmm ok, do you know how I can change the data being sent then?

Comment: then handle 'end' event to end the response res.end();

Comment: @gp. Oh I see, I'll try this in 1 hour I'm out to lunch, please stand by :)

Comment: Btw, do not forget to handle error for your stream. html.on('error', function(err){ /* code */ });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modifying local variable in 'data' event handler function is not going to change the data being sent in response.

Instead of pipe, write the data in 'data' event handler function and end the response in 'end' event handler function.

Just the modified bit

```
html.on('data', function(data) { // <-- here I try to use the template text
  data = data.toString().replace('{title}', title);
  console.log(data);
  res.write(data);
});
html.on('end', function(data) {
  res.end();
});

//html.pipe(res);
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try it as soon as I'm back on my computer, question: will this continue to be asynchronous? I don't know if your changes affect such behavior or in fact improve upon it... because I'm still learning

Comment: @AGE let us know if this answer works. I have another answer using a transform stream.

Comment: @jmugz3 it worked, I like the solution however I did not get an answer regarding if this is asynchronous or not, I would love for it to be since it is a well known "best practice" to use streams in NodeJS as often as you can.

Comment: @gp. Why should I use `end()` instead of `pipe()`? Will the following be correct/better/worse? `html.on('end', function(data) { html.pipe(res); });`... no idea over here

Comment: it's async u can check for urself